# What is the simplest way to create an NSDate with a specific value?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I often need to do this to create `NSDate` objects to compare against in tests—to make sure a timestamp specified in millis past the Epoch UTC in a JSON file is parsed correctly, for example.

What is the correct way to do this in Objective-C with the least boilerplate?

Comment: Thanks driveby downvoter, that was really helpful! The point was not that the answer is necessarily difficult, but that the obvious answer seems to me like way too much boilerplate and whether NSDateFormatter supports ISO8601 out-of-the-box is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The "obvious" version is three lines:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1997-07-27T09:00:00Z"];
```

Comment: Expensive!  Use `NSDateComponents` instead.

Comment: If you've got a better answer, there's a button down below marked "Add Another Answer"...

Comment: It would be a duplicate, so I'll mark the question as a dupe.

Comment: Yeah, use NSDateComponents like in the linked answer above. If you *really* want a one-liner, wrap it in a macro or in a helper function.